# Domain without the 'www.' gives me the Apache 'It works!' page

Tags: apache-2.2

When I enter in my domain like this

```
www.domain.com
```

everything works fine. But when I enter it like this

```
domain.com
```

I get the 'It works!' page. I'm a complete Apache newb so I'm not exactly sure whats going wrong here.

Answer (score 16):

Traditional solution: in the httpd configuration, find:

```
ServerName www.domain.com
```

and add:

```
ServerAlias domain.com
```

However, this will give you a server that responds with the same content on `domain.com` and `www.domain.com`. It's generally considered preferable (particularly SEO-wise) to have only one canonical hostname. To do that, add a new virtual server for the redirect, instead of the alias.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) at your apache config file, make sure that the regex is correct for redirection.

Comment: I don't understand the previous -1, checking if mod_alias is enabled is a good tip.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the Apache config as others have stated.

Simply added a ServerAlias to the apache config for your virtualhost will do it for you. I don't think that it is good practice to create another virtualhost have it redirect for you.

It is good SEO practice to direct everything to one or the other, I suggest using this in either you config file or in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Why do you not think it is good practice to have a virtualhost do the redirect? It is simpler and has less performance impact than processing everything with mod_rewrite.

Comment: I think it is partly to do with preference, but if you have to manage hundreds of virtualhosts, it can become cumbersome to keep all these 'stub' virtualhost up to date and organized. I think there use to be a problem with apache loading up a lot of virtualhost, not sure if this is a problem with apache still. If you are just hosting one or two sites it isn't too big of a deal.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is that the default site is catching the traffic. This worked for me - if you don't care about disabling the default site altogether:

```
a2dissite 000-default
service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and found my solution [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/apache-hits-wrong-virtualhost-without-www-prefix-706981/).

Basically, after an upgrade, Apache put a symlink in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. Deleting everything between and including `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `<VirtualHost>` got everything working for me again.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the exactly same problem. However, my solution was not among the ones already discussed, so it is worth to share.

In my scenario, I had upgraded Apache, but the symlink was not there, as in the case of @Hannele. I have few sites into the same VPS. All, *except one*, were working with or without `www` using similar simple .conf as following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite1.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite1.com
    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/apps/myappname1/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory "/home/myuser/apps/myappname1/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

By chance I have looked into the `apachectl -V`, and there was a warning. As *nothing* had changed, but the upgrade of Apache and the reboot on my VPS, I'd thought it would worth to solve this warning and see ... and it worked! Bellow is the warning:

```
Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
```

I solved the warning as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/396048), i.e.:

1. Create a `servername.conf` file: `sudo vi /etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf`
2. Add `ServerName localhost` to `servername.conf`
3. Run `sudo a2enconf servername`
4. Reload apache: `sudo systemctl reload apache2`

And the sole site which did not worked without `www` (redirected to "It Works" page) is now working!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was different from all of those posted here so far.

**Check your server's hostname.** In my case, I had set the hostname of my server to be the same as one of my domain names e.g. `example.com`. When someone tried to access `http://example.com`, it resulted in Apache's default/blank page because it was serving the `_default_` VirtualHost.

I presume this was happening beacuse Apache was resolving the default localhost address as `example.com`. To fix it, I did two things (although either/or may work):

1. Changed my hostname to `somethingelse` using `hostname somethingelse` and editing `/etc/sysconfig/network`.
2. Added a random `ServerName random_nonexistent_string` to the default VirtualHost block.

Comment: You should not change your hostname for this! Sometimes that could even cause other problems on another services. Apache only falls back to `/etc/hostname` if the `ServerName` is not specified. From [ServerName Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername): "If no ServerName is specified, the server attempts to deduce the client visible hostname by first asking the operating system for the system hostname, and if that fails, performing a reverse lookup on an IP address present on the system."

Comment: @EsaJokinen That explains why it used my hostname, because I had not specified a ServerName for the default VirtualHost. Changing my hostname was not a risk because I don't use it for anything else.