# Apache Configuration Issue - website without www going to default site

Tags: apache-2.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Domain without the 'www.' gives me the Apache 'It works!' page](https://serverfault.com/questions/94014/domain-without-the-www-gives-me-the-apache-it-works-page)

I have included a copy of my virtual host file for apache below. (However I have hidden the ip address and domain name for now)

My problem is that the following work:
www.mydomainnamehere.org
www.mydomainnamehere.com
mydomainnamehere.com

This one doesn't work:
mydomainnamehere.org - instead of going to the document root listed below, it goes to the document root of the default site.

What could be causing this?

```
<VirtualHost [ipaddresshidden]:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomainnamehere.org
ServerName mydomainnamehere.org
ServerAlias www.mydomainnamehere.org
ServerAlias mydomainnamehere.com
ServerAlias www.mydomainnamehere.com
DocumentRoot /home/www/mydomainnamehere.org/html/
ErrorLog /home/www/mydomainnamehere.org/logs/error.log
CustomLog /home/www/mydomainnamehere.org/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Just a tip, use one `ServerAlias` line with each additional domain separated by a space.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's get the most obvious things out of the way.

1. Did you restart apache after adding mydomainhere.org ?
2. Have you tried this in a different browser? Sometimes browsers cache the default home page very aggressively.
3. What is the ServerName in the default httpd.conf? Is there a conflict in servernames by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and found my solution [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/apache-hits-wrong-virtualhost-without-www-prefix-706981/).

Basically, after an upgrade, Apache put a symlink in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. Deleting everything between and including `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `<VirtualHost>` got everything working for me again.